# replace more number 9 9 9 9 to character

Tags: php, str-replace

[php]
I want replace all if have {space}{number}{space} to -> {space}{chart}{space}

in 9 9 9 9 
out Do Do Do Do

Code below error

$string= ' 9 9 9 9 ';

$string = str_replace(' 9 ', ' Do ', $string);

it return **Do 9 Do 9**

Please Andy help?

Comment: Who on earth is Andy?

Comment: =any one@@ no eny where@@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace instead. Lookahead and Lookbehind  group test that there are  spaces before and after a digit

```
echo $string = preg_replace('/(?<=\s)\d(?=\s)/', 'Do', $string);
```